# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&', what the reason?

Tags: c++, function, reference, post-increment

I have the given code, which gets an error:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&'
>   from an rvalue of type 'int'   const int b = f(a++);
>                        ^

```
int f(int& a)
{
    return a;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int a = 5;
    int b = f(a++);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What the cause of this error ?

Comment: does it compile without post-increment?

Comment: Does it work if you change to the pre version: `int b = f(++a);`? the problem could be that the postfix version returns a temporary object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postfix increment operator on an `int` returns a temporary value. A temporary value cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference, because modifying that temporary doesn't make sense. You are trying to bind the temporary to an `int&`, which is giving an error.

To fix this, either use the pre-increment operator (`++a`), or take your argument by value (it's better to pass builtin types as value rather than `const T&`):

```
int f(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Post-increment (`a++`) increments `a` and returns a temporary with `a`'s old value.

Why are you passing by non-`const` reference? - it doesn't look like you're changing the parameter inside the function, just just pass by value or `const` reference.

If you were changing the parameter, what would you expect the behavior to be, considering `a++` already changes it? Would the change be intuitive? Legal?

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
int f(int& a)
```

accepts **non-const reference**. Such references must always point to a valid objects, residing at certain memory locations **(*)**.

Post incrementation works as follows:

```
 - save current value as `r`
 - increment original variable
 - return `r`
```

That's because result of post-incrementation is a temporary, yielding value from before incrementation. Such temporary must be passed either as value or const reference:

```
int f(int a) //This will work
int f(const int& a) //And this
```

---

**(*)** In fact, older compilers allowed for such constrcuts. For example, this code will compile under VC6:

```
struct T {};

void f(T& t)
{
}

int main()
{
    f(T());
}
```

However, such behaviour is not standard-compliant.